# JUnit: Is there any difference between running a Suite, and running tests individually?

Tags: java, junit

I am having a problem, one test class seems to be interfering with the other in my test suite.

I have a suite, which executes two classes, one is called MergeTestSuite.java (which is another Suite), and the other is called RecordTest.java.
RecordTest extends one class already tested by MergeTestSuite.java

I created another suite as follows:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses( {

   MergeTestSuite.class,
   RecordTest.class

})
public class CoreTestSuite {


   @BeforeClass
   public static void install() throws Throwable {
    RegistryUtils.cleanupResources();
   }
}
```

Both MergeTestSuite.class and RecordTest.class run fine individually. If I run CoreTestSuite, the second test will fail, unless I remove MergeTestSuite.class from the list.

Comment: Please post the code in your actual question. How can we tell why the second test *will fail* and solve the issue, without any code?

Answer (score 1):

A Junit TestSuite provides extra features for multiple tests.  For instance,  you can control the order in which the tests run and you can also combine multiple test suites into another suite.  I think this [older doc from Junit 3.1.8](http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm) describes it best.